# javascript getelementby name

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm using radio button with 4 region values

```js
(function() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByName("regio1").value);
})();
```

```html
<input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio1" value="VL" type="radio" checked="">
<label for="regio1" class="text-left">Amsterdam</label>
<div class="field text-left">
  <input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio2" type="radio" value="WA">
  <label for="regio1" class="text-left">London</label>
</div>
<div class="field text-left">
  <input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio3" type="radio" value="BR">
  <label for="regio1" class="text-left">Brussel</label>
</div>
<div class="field text-left">
  <input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio4" type="radio" value="DU">
  <label for="regio1" class="text-left">Hamburg</label>
</div>
```

When using `alert` `getElementsByName` then getting error value is `undefined`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: see the edited answer . It will show all values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the checked one using the `:checked` pseudo-selector...

```js
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(document.querySelector("[name=regio]:checked").value);
});
```

```html
<input class="selectOwner" name="regio" id="regio1" value="VL" type="radio" checked="">
<label for="regio1" class="text-left">Amsterdam</label>
<br/>
<input class="selectOwner" name="regio" id="regio2" type="radio" value="WA">
<label for="regio2" class="text-left">London</label>
<br/>
<input class="selectOwner" name="regio" id="regio3" type="radio" value="BR">
<label for="regio3" class="text-left">Brussel</label>
<br/>
<input class="selectOwner" name="regio" id="regio4" type="radio" value="DU">
<label for="regio4" class="text-left">Hamburg</label>
<br/>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

I also changed the radio group name to `regio`, and fixed the label attachment.

Comment: No problem - glad to help :)

Comment: Pay attention to [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens Do you want to be more specific?

Comment: The link is very especific.

Comment: @Archer how can i obtain value from select options, i tried the same code but it's not working for options.

Comment: <select id="point1pillers" name="thirdpillers">
                                                    <option value="1">0 - 5</option>
                                                    <option value="2">6 - 8 </option>
                                                    <option value="3">9 - 11</option>
                                                    <option value="4">12 - 14</option>                                          
</select>

Comment: @Zaheen, you have to take the `select` and get its value.

Comment: You could use `document.querySelector("#point1pillers").value;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use  document.getElementsByName("regio1");
It will return all the nodes with regio1

If you want the value for

```
<input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio1" value="VL" type="radio" checked=""><label for="regio1" class="text-left">Amsterdam</label>
```

then You have to use

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("regio1");
var y = x[0].value
```

and the value of y has your desired value

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify which one you want to alert. For example if you want to alert your first regio1 then you would write something like this. 0 being the index and the first item.

```
alert(document.getElementsByName("regio1")[0].value);
```

Answer (score -2):

Look this code:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByName( "regio1" );
for (var i in elems) {
  var elem = elems[ i ];
  if ( elems[ i ].checked )
    alert( elem.value )
}
```

```html
<input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio1" value="VL" type="radio" checked="">
<label for="regio1" class="text-left">Amsterdam</label>

<input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio2" type="radio" value="WA">
<label for="regio1" class="text-left">London</label>

<input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio3" type="radio" value="BR">
<label for="regio1" class="text-left">Brussel</label>

<input class="selectOwner" name="regio1" id="regio4" type="radio" value="DU">
<label for="regio1" class="text-left">Hamburg</label>
```

Comment: Why is it not useful?

Answer (score -3):

`document.getElementsByName` gets a list of HTML elements, is not an unique element.

Comment: If you're not going to answer the question then you should post comments, not answers.  If you can't post comments then you need to post actual answers or don't post at all.

Comment: This is a answer! He asked why it is undefined result.

Comment: He doesn't ask that - he asks for help and it is very clear what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: This is far from being a **proper answer**.

Comment: It is not clear at all! His problem is with the property because it is unexpectly (for him) undefined.

Comment: To which question?